# Rails 4: development.log file not getting updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I accidentally deleted development.log file.
Now the development logs are not getting generated. 
Even if I create an empty development.log file its not getting updated with logs.
How this issue can be fixed.

Comment: Did you ever solve this. i did the same thing, accidentally hitting move to trash instead of clear display in the mac console.

Answer (score 0):

restarting the server may fix the problem.